# firebase-tools for hosting: bootstrap not working

Tags: firebase

firebase bootstrap gets the error message (on Windows 7):
Installation Error - Couldn't relocate project assets

All other firbase commands (init, deploy, login, ...) are working fine.

Comment: Can you reach out to us at support@firebase.com?

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in v1.0.1 of firebase-tools, if you're still seeing this issue, run `npm update -g firebase-tools` to get the latest version (v1.1.4 at the time of writing)

Comment: I've installed the latest version of firebase-tools (1.1.4 at the moment). It still doesn't work.

Comment: @dnemoga can you reach out to us at support@firebase.com with some datails on your setup and specifically what versions of Windows and node you're running